# How to get an accumulative counting of rows in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame (called `u`) in which one of the columns (called `dates`) contains dates. Now I would like to generate another data frame which containing all the dates between the minimal and maximal dates from the `u` table (each row correspond to a date). In the new data frame I also would like to have a column that indicated how many rows from the first table have a smaller date.

For example of the first table is like that:

```
| a | 2015-01-01 |
| b | 2015-01-01 |
| c | 2015-01-03 |
| d | 2015-01-04 |
```

Then the second data frame has to be like that:

```
| 2015-01-01 | 0 |
| 2015-01-02 | 2 |
| 2015-01-03 | 2 |
| 2015-01-04 | 3 |
```

I wrote a code that does exactly what I need, but it is extremely slow and not elegant. This is what I have:

```
min_date = u.dates.min()
max_date = u.dates.max()
dates = []
date = min_date
while True:
    dates.append(date)
    if date == max_date:
        break
    date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

date2n = {}
for date in dates:
    n = len(u[u.dates < date]) 
    date2n[date] = n
```

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

Get the count for each date group and take the cumulative sum:

```
In [3]: u1 = u.groupby('dates')['dates'].count().cumsum()

In [4]: u1
Out[4]: 
dates
2015-01-01    2
2015-01-03    3
2015-01-04    4
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

This gives us the count for dates less than *or equal to* the given one, so we need to shift by one day:

```
In [5]: u2 = u1.shift(1, freq='d')

In [6]: u2
Out[6]: 
dates
2015-01-02    2
2015-01-04    3
2015-01-05    4
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

Reindex to get the missing dates in the range:

```
In [7]: u3 = u2.reindex(min_date, max_date)

In [8]: u3
Out[8]: 
2015-01-01   NaN
2015-01-02     2
2015-01-03   NaN
2015-01-04     3
Freq: D, Name: dates, dtype: float64
```

Fill in the missing values by forward filling, and fill in the first entry with 0:

```
In [9]: u4 = u3.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)

In [10]: u4
Out[10]: 
2015-01-01    0
2015-01-02    2
2015-01-03    2
2015-01-04    3
Freq: D, Name: dates, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd add a new col using [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html#pandas.date_range) passing the `min` and `max` date values, then call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) on a df with a single column passing param `axis=1` to `apply` row-wise, you can then count the number of rows that meet your condition using [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas.Series.sum) (as this will convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`) and add this as a new column:

```
In [235]:
df['date_range'] = pd.date_range(start=df['dates'].min(), end=df['dates'].max())
df
​
Out[235]:
  Col1      dates date_range
0    a 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
1    b 2015-01-01 2015-01-02
2    c 2015-01-03 2015-01-03
3    d 2015-01-04 2015-01-04

In [255]:
df['count'] = df[['date_range']].apply(lambda x: (df['dates'] < x.values[0]).sum(), axis=1)
df

Out[255]:
  Col1      dates date_range  count
0    a 2015-01-01 2015-01-01      0
1    b 2015-01-01 2015-01-02      2
2    c 2015-01-03 2015-01-03      2
3    d 2015-01-04 2015-01-04      3
```

**EDIT**

Based on your new info:

```
In [256]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""a  2015-01-01
 b  2015-01-01
 c  2015-01-03
 d  2015-01-06"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', parse_dates=[1], names=['Col1', 'dates'])
df

Out[256]:
  Col1      dates
0    a 2015-01-01
1    b 2015-01-01
2    c 2015-01-03
3    d 2015-01-06

In [257]:    
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date_range':pd.date_range(start=df['dates'].min(), end=df['dates'].max())})
df1

Out[257]:
  date_range
0 2015-01-01
1 2015-01-02
2 2015-01-03
3 2015-01-04
4 2015-01-05
5 2015-01-06

In [258]:
df1['count'] = df1['date_range'].apply(lambda x: (df['dates'] < x).sum())

df1

Out[258]:
  date_range  count
0 2015-01-01      0
1 2015-01-02      2
2 2015-01-03      2
3 2015-01-04      3
4 2015-01-05      3
5 2015-01-06      3
```

So I'd construct a new df with a date range, you can just call apply on this and `sum` the number of rows that meet your condition.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear from my toy example, but in my case not all dates are present in the first data frame. Some dates, however, are present more than one time (like in the example I gave). So, for me the first command (which defined date_range column) does not work since the number of dates is not equal to the number of rows in the data frame.

Comment: Well we can't help you if you're not **clear** can we?

Comment: On the other hand I never said that in the first data frame all dates are present. So, it was just your assumption.